# Access to Object JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can I access a propertie from this object?

[image: An Object]

I just want to get the 'responseText' propertie.

This object come from this function:

```
function freight(cep){

var response = $.post("./getFrete.php", {cep_destino: cep}, function(data){
    return data
});

console.log(response);
```

}

I've been trying to resolve it with "object_name['responseText']" and "object_name.responseText", but without success yet.

Comment: Please include code as text, not as an image. Also, please show what you've tried, and what research you've done into solving the issue yourself. [ask] is a good resource for knowing what is expected of questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: `object.responseText` just like accessing a property of any other object.

Comment: Please consider taking the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and reading [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Given that that's an Ajax response, pretty sure that the real problem is trying to access the object before it exists.

Comment: Ayup. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 0):

Given an object named `x` with a property named `y`, we can access the property as `x.y`.

In your particular case, it looks like you have an object that represents the response to some sort of HTTP request. So, assuming that that object has been assigned to a variable named `response`, then you can access the `statusText` property as `response.statusText`.

```
response.statusText
```

Comment: You're right, it's an http request, but I'm getting de same mistake yet. Is returning "undefined". I'll edit my post end put my function there.